# php imagick resize lost quality

Tags: php, resize, imagick

I have a function:

```
public static function resize($data, $w, $h)
{
    $image = new Imagick();       
    $image->readImageBlob($data); 
    $image->scaleImage($w, $h);   
    $data = $image->getImageBlob();
    return $data;
}
```

`$data` is the binary string format of an image, its origin size is 720x1280. In my case, `$w` is 180,`$h` is 320.

I display the `$data` by outputing it to web page.

But it is not as clear as the origin one.

Could anybody tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try passing third parameter `true`. `$image->scaleImage($w, $h,true);  `

Comment: I've tried it, not work :).

Comment: Than probably try resize option rather than scale image.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try resize image :

```
<?php

$thumb = new Imagick('myimage.gif');

$thumb->resizeImage(320,240,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$thumb->writeImage('mythumb.gif');

$thumb->destroy(); 

?>
```